# Matplotlib X-ticks not distributing correctly

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have a plot as shown below that has over 1000 x-axis points. I'm trying to scale the x-axis into 3 values, the min, mid & max value instead of having 1000 labels.

Despite my efforts denoted within the hashtags, all 3 values are written onto the same tick (on top of each other) or simply only 1 tick is randomly placed along the x-axis.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matlplotlib.pyplot import figure

figure (num = None, figsize=(20,10), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')

ax =plt.gca()
data.plot(kind='bar', x='colA', y='colB', ax=ax)

######
plt.xticks(np.arrange(0,3, step 1)

**ALSO TRIED**

plt.xticks = ([1,2,3], ["a","b","c"])

######
plt.show()
```

How can I distribute the min,mid and max value evenly across the X-axis?

Comment: what is the result of `data.dtypes`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If 'colA' is numerical:

```py
x_min = min(data['colA'])
x_max = max(data['colA'])
x_mid = (x_min + x_max) / 2
   # use regular division if the numbers are floats, use integer division in case all numbers are integers
plt.xticks([x_min, x_mid, x_max], ["a","b","c"])
# plt.xticks([x_min, x_mid, x_max])  # leave out the labels if the default labels are OK
```

If, on the contrary, 'colA' is categorical (so, some strings), they are numbered internally as `0, 1, 2, ...` up till the number of strings minus one:

```py
x_min = 0
x_max = len(data['colA']) - 1
x_mid = x_max // 2  # integer division
plt.xticks([x_min, x_mid, x_max])
```

Comment: Exact same thing happens, the ticks are just stacked on top of each other..I opted out for the 'plotly' library which resolved my issue. However, still doesn't answer this question..

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
min_ = min(data['colA'])
max_ = max(data['colA'])
mid_ = (min_ + max_) / 2.
ax.set_xticks([min_, mid_, max_])
ax.set_xticklabels(['min', 'mid', 'max'])
```